# Word Document created does not convert to PDF

Tags: vba, compiler-errors, pdf-generation

Generated Word Document does not convert to PDF

I generate a Word Document populating the bookmarks within it from excel and then tried exporting to PDF. Constantly getting error even after adding Microsoft Word Library 16.0. What am I doing wrong here?

Option Explicit

```
Sub GenerateTerminationLetter()

    Dim objWord As Object, docWord As Object
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim xlName As Name
    Dim Path, SavePath, TempPath, FileName3 As String
    Dim EmpFileName As String


        Set wb = ThisWorkbook

    ' ******************************* Primary Letter Template Location ***********************
    Sheets("FilePath").Select
        TempPath = Sheets("FilePath").Range("C16").Value
            If Right(TempPath, 1) <> "\" Then
                    TempPath = TempPath & "\"
                Else
            End If
        Path = TempPath & "Termination Letter (Redundancy A023 FPP) (NEW - With Whistle Blowing Statement).docx"

    '*******************************Populate Bookmarks ***************************************
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
     'Create a new Word Session
                Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
     'Open document in word
                Set docWord = objWord.Documents.Add(Path)
     'Loop through names in the activeworkbook
    For Each xlName In wb.Names
         'if xlName's name exists in the document then put the value at the bookmark
        If docWord.Bookmarks.Exists(xlName.Name) Then
            docWord.Bookmarks(xlName.Name).Range.Text = Range(xlName.Value)
        End If
    Next xlName
    Sheets("Temp").Visible = xlVeryHidden

    '******************************* Activate word and display document **********************

    With objWord
        .Visible = True
        .Activate
    End With
    'Save Termination Letter
    FileName3 = Sheets("R-Copy").Range("D7").Value
    '******************************* Export as PDF ********************************************
    docWord.ExportAsFixedFormat _
    Type:=xlTypePDF, _
    Filename:=EmpFolder & "\" & "Termination Letter_" & FileName3, _
    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
    ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF


    objWord.Quit
    'Release the Word object to save memory and exit macro

    ErrorExit:
                Set objWord = Nothing
                Exit Sub

    'Error Handling routine


    ErrorHandler:

       If Err Then
          MsgBox "Error No: " & Err.Number & "; There is a problem. Contact Administrator"
             If Not objWord Is Nothing Then objWord.Quit False
                Resume ErrorExit
       End If
    End Sub
```

Error No. 448: Contact Administrator

Comment: Which line is triggering the error?  I'm assuming its the exportAsFixedFormat line.  Error 448 is Named argument not found, and it looks like Type isn't one of the allowed arguments.  A little more information and a link to the reference for the method is in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Which line is triggering the error?  I'm assuming its the exportAsFixedFormat line.  Error 448 is Named argument not found, and it looks like Type isn't one of the allowed arguments.  You problably want ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF, which it looks like you've included, but Type isn't an allowed argument, and will cause an error.  Here's the docs on that method: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.document.exportasfixedformat

It looks like some of the other arguments you're using aren't quite right, too, since they're referencing xl instead of wd types and the property names don't quite line up.  Try:

```
docWord.ExportAsFixedFormat _
    OutputFileName:=EmpFolder & "\" & "Termination Letter_" & FileName3, _
    IncludeDocProps:=True, _
    ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF
```

Also, I don't believe you are setting EmpFolder anywhere, so it's an empty variable, which is probably either going to make the method fail or cause it to save the file in the wrong place.

Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: Yes you are right. Its the ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF where the error occurs. EmpFolder is a Global variable defined in a different procedure. I have checked that the EmpFolder actually does hold a value and is not blank.

Comment: @SydneyNumpty do you have a reference to`Microsoft Office Word` set? Otherwise you can't use the word enumerators like`wdExportFormatPDF`. You can check by simply adding an [Òption Explicit](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/DeclaringVariables.aspx) (always use it) to the top of the module where the code stays. If you get an error after that (var not defined), you have to set the [values for those enums](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.wdexportformat) by definfing them as constants or rerplace them by their values (not recommended)

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub BatchConvertDocxToPDF()

Dim objDoc1, objWord1 As Object
Dim strFile As String, strFolder, fp As String

'Initialization

 strFolder = EmpFolder & "\"
 strFile = Dir(strFolder & "*.docx", vbNormal)
 xp = strFolder & strFile


'Process each file in the file folder and convert them to pdf.

Dim objWord As Object
Dim objDoc  As Object

                Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
                objWord.Visible = True

  While strFile <> ""

                Set objDoc1 = objWord.Documents.Open(Filename:=strFolder & strFile)
                objDoc1.ExportAsFixedFormat _
                OutputFileName:=Replace(objDoc1.FullName, ".docx", ".pdf"), _
                ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF, OpenAfterExport:=False, 
                OptimizeFor:=wdExportOptimizeForPrint, _
                Range:=wdExportAllDocument, Item:=wdExportDocumentContent

                objDoc1.Close
                strFile = Dir()
  Wend
       objWord.Visible = False
       Set objDoc1 = Nothing
       Set objWord = Nothing
  End Sub
```

Comment: The above Code finally worked. Looks like I had to open up an instance of Word for the PDF file to be created.